# Adding Custom UIView to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

(iOS/Xcode Question) How do you programmatically add a custom `UIView` (with labels and buttons) to a `UITableViewController`?
When I try to do this:

```
CGFloat x = (self.tableView.bounds.size.width / 2);
CGFloat y = (self.tableView.bounds.size.height / 2);
NewView *newView = [[NewView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 417, 228)];
[self.tableView addSubView:newView];
```

-all I get is a black rectangle.

*edit
So I figured it out. I forgot to load the nib.

```
CGFloat x = (self.view.bounds.size.width / 2);
CGFloat y = (self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);

NewView *newView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

newView.center = CGPointMake(x, y);

[self.tableView addSubview:newView];
```

Comment: Read the documentation on delegate and datasource for UITableView.  Don't add it directly to the table view.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: If you want a view above or below the normal tableview rows, you could do: `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:newView]` instead of addSubView.

Comment: Why are you trying to add a view to UITableViewController??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your are trying to add an view to `UITableView`, which works not as you expected. `UITableView` contains a set of `UITableViewCell`. Please read the documentation for UITableView, its delegate and data source.

Comment: It is possible to add subviews to table views directly. Table views are `UIView` subclasses. That is not necessarily the problem.

Comment: @LeoNatan We don't know if `UITableView` overrides `addSubView:` method. But we know that it overrides at least `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Overriding either is irrelevant. If `addSubView:` is overridden to not add subviews, that would be bad programming. This is not the case of `UITableView`; you can subviews to table views.

Comment: Nathan- that's what I thought. Oh well guess I'll have to go over the documentation again. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a UITableViewController along with a custom UIView, use UIViewController Containment.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html